# Determine npm package dependency chain

Tags: node.js, npm, npm-install

I run `npm install` on a project and get a deprecation error for an underlying dependency.

It is not a direct dependency, it's in node_modules. How can I easily figure out which of my dependencies eventually depends on the problematic library?

A first-pass solution is to use grep, but 2 issues:

1. This will help me locate the package.json containing the problematic dependency, but there could be 2, 3, 4...n packages between that and my own project's package.json
2. grep is a bit slow

Comment: like, I wrote this whole SO question and I'm still waiting on grep

Comment: You could take a look at your package-lock.json file instead. Should become more clear if you just search through there.

Answer (score 1):

What's wrong with using `npm ls`? Here's sample output for a module:

```sh
➜  node-address-rfc2821 git:(master) npm ls
address-rfc2821@2.0.0 /Users/matt/git/node-address-rfc2821
├─┬ nearley@2.20.1
│ ├── commander@2.20.3
│ ├── moo@0.5.1
│ ├── railroad-diagrams@1.0.0
│ └─┬ randexp@0.4.6
│   ├── discontinuous-range@1.0.0
│   └── ret@0.1.15
└── punycode@2.1.1
```

The command `npm ls` has been around since at least [2011](https://nodejs.org/en/blog/npm/npm-1-0-the-new-ls/)